# css background repeating from 300px onwards

Tags: css, background, repeat

I am wondering if anyone knows how to achieve the following - take a look at http://www.dspts.si

The first 1/3rd of the screen has an empty background and from there onwards there should be a pattern repeating. I did it right now, by creating a very long pattern png and set it to offset 300 and repeat-x. However, I'm not happy with this solution because it will break if the pages ever get longer than the background image png is.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the repeating pattern as background to `html` element, then a white 1px * 300px image as an background image to `body` element, and you're all set.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

html {
    background: url(dotted.png);
}

body {
    background: url(white_1x300.png) 0 0 repeat-x;
}
```

You don't have to use `html` and `body` tags for this, but it's the easiest way and doesn't require any new markup.

Comment: Is it not possible with just 1 image?

Comment: No, as you can't fake the white 300px high area with elements, and you can't combine the images as the html background needs to be repeating.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify multiple backgrounds. See [Can I have multiple background images using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423172/can-i-have-multiple-background-images-using-css). The techniques mentioned there are:

- Put the whole page into another `<div>` container or misuse the `<html>` tag for it.
  This means you specify a background for `<body>` and one for `<html>`.
- Use CSS3 which support multiple background images. That's not yet supported by all common browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, specify your background image as normal but set the `background-position` like this:

```
background-position:0 300px;
```

This will make the background image start at 0px from the left, and 300px from the top.

Let's not forget that you can use [FireBug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) with [FireFox](http://www.mozilla-europe.org/en/firefox/) to easily diagnose techniques on websites.

Comment: and can you still use repeat-y, then?

Comment: Ah fair point :D, didn't spot that http://www.dspts.si/ used a very long thin image repeated.

My bad

Comment: yes, well, this is what I have done right now with the position. if I do repeat-y it will for some reason wrap around and I'll have pattern on the top as well. :(