# Layered Backgrounds in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, background, css

```
background-image: url('/images/tenticles.png'), url('/images/header.png');
```

I have the above code, which works in both Firefox and Chrome. However it does not work in IE8. I was wondering if there was a way around this not working. Something similar to HTML5shiv.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple workarounds for IE's lack of [multiple background support](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/background.html). One such technique involves simply creating a `div` that spans the entire page, and setting its background along with the background of the `body` element. This technique can be repeated as necessary. For example:

```
body { background-url('/images/tenticles.png'); }
#background1 { background-url('/images/header.png'); }

<body>
    <div id="background1">
    </div>
</body>
```

However, it looks like you want something along the lines of [CSS3 PIE (Progressive Internet Explorer)](http://css3pie.com/), which "makes Internet Explorer 6-8 capable of rendering several of the most useful CSS3 decoration features". From PIE's website:

> PIE currently has full or partial support for the following CSS3 features:
>
> - border-radius
> - box-shadow
> - border-image
> - multiple background images
> - linear-gradient as background image
>
> Other features are under active development.

Note that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423172/can-i-have-multiple-background-images-using-css) is very similar and has a lot of other useful information and techniques.

Comment: Thanks, I found PIE while looking for a solution but it didn't seem to work when I tested it. I'll mess around with it a little longer to see if I did something wrong.

Comment: @Arimil Gotcha; if you're still having problems with it I can think of a good place to ask for help...