# IE Not loading my images from CSS

Tags: css, internet-explorer

[My site](http://createstudios.org.uk) appears fine in FF & Chrome, but load it in Ie (tested in 7 & 8) and none of the background images load.

The CSS appears to load properly,  just the images are not showing up. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using multiple background images, which are [not supported by IE up to 8](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html).

```
background: url('../images/main-background.png') no-repeat, 
            url('../images/main-background-repeat.png') repeat-y;
```

Comment: Yup. See [this earlier answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423172/can-i-have-multiple-background-images-using-css). Best thing might be to have an ie-specific stylesheet for IE versions lower than 9 to substitute a single (and possibly not so good-looking) background.

Comment: Spot on. I just moved the more important of the multiple background images into their own earlier style. Browsers that support multiple background images will use the later defined, as per the rules of the cascade, and IE will ignore the later rule and use the first one defined.

It means that IE users don't get to see the full design, but hey, they don't deserve too!! ;)