# css image on top of another for website background

Tags: css, image

Hi there I am trying to make and image on top of another in 1 tag.

Basically I want an image to be the banner on top, so repeat-x
then under it I want the background image repeated multiple times

So something like this

```
body
{
 background:url(banner.jpg); repeat: repeat-x;
 background:url(background.jpg); 
}
```

not 100% sure how to do it...I think that explains how I would like it.

I may also want something on the bottom added later so like after that background is done I would want something like background:url(footer.jpg) repeat: repeat-x; bottom

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423172/can-i-have-multiple-background-images-using-css -- this SO question outlines the CSS3 implementation you're hoping for without being add extra markup easily.

Comment: thanks it explains it very well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS3 has support for multiple backgrounds on a single element; this is relatively widely supported, except for IE <= 8. You can write the following:

```
body
{
  background-image: url(banner.jpg), url(background.jpg);
  background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat;
}
```

Comment: No worries. You should be aware that the fallback in browsers which don't support multiple backgrounds is to display _nothing_. If you care about IE6-8, you will want another method, or a fallback via, say, http://www.modernizr.com

Answer (score 4):

Im thinking this is what youre after.

http://jsfiddle.net/wpqDy/

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url("bg.jpg") repeat 0px 3px;
}

body {
    background: url("bg_top.jpg") repeat-x top left;    
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I tried this it did work but I went with the css3 method. But that jsfiddle tool I had a little play with, it's really cool :)

Comment: The websites niche is more towards people who are quite decent with computers already and are younger folk so I think IE6-IE8 wont be such an issue, if it does not load it's still alright because I have a decent white background which still makes the site completely usable :)
I'd rather advocate css3 so more people start updating browsers :P

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to put background images on two different containers.  Perhaps something like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="page">
    <div id="content">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</body>


#page
{
  background:url(background.jpg); 
}

#content
{
  background:url(banner.jpg); repeat: repeat x;
}
```

Comment: not an option. The template on how the software is made wont allow it...well it would be far too much editing and looking through files to do it.

http://www.minecraftforum.net/

have a look at their background...I want to do something like that. I looked at their css and I tried it but it did not work

Comment: Perhaps you should mention something about your weird template restrictions in the question?