# Create button using 3 images

Tags: css

I've 3 images, a center block that should be repeated and two end parts (left and right).
I want to be able to generate the button below using these three images.

Here is the complete button.

[image: Button]

*Sorry for the dark background.*

I've this code so far.

```
li {
  background-image: url(/images/middle.png), url(/images/right.png), url(/images/left.png);
  background-position: center, right, left;
  background-repeat: repeat-x, no-repeat, no-repeat;
}
```

Which generates this button.

[image: Button 2]

Anyone knows why my button looks like it does and how to render the first button above?
I must use the 3 given images. And no, this isn't an home/school assignment :)

EDIT: I found [this](http://css.flepstudio.org/en/css-tutorials/css-button-expandable-in-width.html) tutorial on how to solve the problem. Isn't there a better way to solve the problem, maybe a more semantic way?

Comment: Could you give us the middle.png, right.png, and left.png too? Helps us to test with home-brewn code. :)

Comment: If you target browsers which implement CSS3 maybe should you use `border-radius`, `linear gradients` and `box-shadow` instead of images?

Comment: @Jarno Sure, here they're http://imgur.com/a/vxha5 Right, left, middle. In that order.

Comment: @MatTheCat I must use the given images.

Comment: With that code alone, I get a bulletin + button that spans over the width of the page. Do you see the same issue?

Comment: Jarno Try this code; https://gist.github.com/b92df1da54f64a7f801d

Comment: @MatTheCat Some UI guy at my company has decided that we should use the given images. I'm just a backend developer, I'm not sure why I'm doing this in the first place :)

Comment: I see, but would be bad if you can render the same effect without images?

Comment: @MatTheCat I did that first using plain CSS(3), but was told that I should redo it. This is me redoing it :)

Comment: Sad, "UI guys" shouldn't advise developers' work =/ So JohnB solution would be the greatest I think.

Answer (score 1):

*Personally, I would try to keep it as simple as possible and use 1 repeat-x image across the middle of the button, and use CSS3 rounded corners to finish off the edges.  Gracefully degrades as a square button.  A good example is the "Download" button from [JQueryUI.com](http://jqueryui.com/download):*

[image: Download button from JQueryUI.com]

---

**If you only want to support CSS3 compliant browsers, then you can attach multiple images in `background-image`.**

- [Can I have multiple background images using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423172/can-i-have-multiple-background-images-using-css)

**However, pre CSS3, you can only attach 1 `background-image` per HTML element.  You tried to attach 3, and the last 2 images in your CSS are getting ignored.**

*The tutorial that you found is a good solution for the type of button you are trying to create.  It defines at least 3 elements to attach images to.  They use 4, but you can do it with only 3.*

I assume that your HTML looks like this so far:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" title="My Text button">My Text</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So you have 2 elements for which to attach; you need at least 1 more:

```
<ul>
  <li class="link-button">
    <a href="#" title="My Text button"><span>My Text</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Should do it.  Then the CSS:

```
li.link-button {
  background: url(/images/middle.png) repeat-x;
}
.link-button a {
  background: url(/images/left.png) left center no-repeat;
}
.link-button span {
  background: url(/images/right.png) right center no-repeat;
}
```

- [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JePAG/)

*However, you middle repeating image is a different color!*

Comment: Multiply backgrounds are supported in CSS3. So my code should be valid.

Comment: So you are not attempting to support older browsers?  What is your lowest common denominator CSS support degradation plan?

Comment: @JohnB This application won't run in a browser. CSS3 and HTML5 will always be supported.

Comment: This is the simplest solution though I couldn't get it working. The button spans to fill the whole width of the page?

Comment: @Jarno Argillander: `float:left;` on the `<li>`

Comment: @JohnB I'm not sure why, but I'm getting a warning symbol next to the span background in chrome: http://imgur.com/2l40j Any ideas why? EDIT: It's the same thing with the href (a) background.

Comment: What's "links"?  No I don't know why.  I can't help you anymore sorry.

Comment: @Oleander: have you tried with just the code JohnB gave you? Without any additions? (I'm not seeing warning symbols in Chrome)

Answer (score 1):

Here's "old school" version :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }

        ul {
            list-style: none;
        }

        li {
            clear: both;
        }

        .list_button {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .left {
            float: left;
            width: 3px;
            height: 23px;
            background: url("./images/left.png") left center no-repeat;
        }

        .right {
            float: left;
            width: 3px;
            height: 23px;
            background: url("./images/right.png") left center no-repeat;
        }

        .middle {
            float: left;
            height: 23px;
            background: url("./images/middle.png") repeat-x;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="list_button">
                <div class="left"></div>
                <div class="middle">First</div>
                <div class="right"></div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="list_button">
                <div class="left"></div>
                <div class="middle">Second</div>
                <div class="right"></div>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```