# div with 3 backgrounds

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I have multiple background images using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423172/can-i-have-multiple-background-images-using-css)

Is it possible to use 3 different background images in a div?
Imagine a div where the far left is one image (that does not repeat), the middle is another image that repeats horizontally, and the far right is yet another image that does not repeat.
(In much the same way as the header/content/footer model works vertically.)

If it's not possible please show me alternative ways - every way I have tried thus far has failed.

[image]

Comment: I do not understand. Can you show a screenshot or some sample code?

Comment: IMage uploaded - please see it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could actually do this without adding too much extra markup (if any) using the [sliding doors technique](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/). This technique is compatible in all browsers.

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer { /* Apply "left door" styles here */ }
.inner { /* Apply "right door" styles here */ }
```

Let me know if you have any questions/problems with this.

Comment: and what to do with the middle? there are 3 parts left , middle , right

Comment: what about float? my needs to float left - how i mke the left and the right part to be attached to that div?

Comment: You should be able to float your `.outer` div without breaking what you're doing.

Answer (score 3):

With CSS3, it is possible.

http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/

Thing is, People with IE7 and IE8 wont see it... But those with the lastest versions of chrome, firefox, safari, opera, and I think IE9 will be able to see it.

So what is your public?

See this chart: http://caniuse.com/#search=multiple%20backgrounds

Comment: This dont work in IE 7 i need it to work in explorer too...please see my image above

Comment: just tried that code with divs and that dont work:(

Comment: In what browser? And what did you try?

Comment: background: url(/Admin/Style/1.jpg) left top repeat, url(/Admin/Style/2.jpg) right bottom repeat, url(/Admin/Style/3.jpg) left top repeat;   HOW can i make the left and the right parts be exactly width=30px ?