# Why is this code not compatible with ie?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I have multiple background images using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423172/can-i-have-multiple-background-images-using-css)

I am making a website and I am running in to the problem that the site displays fine on Firefox, however doesn't display right in any version of ie that I have tried.(I am not sure about the newer versions of ie, I don't have them installed)
Here is the code

```
#footer {
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    padding: 0px 0 20px 0px;
    background: url(images/footer-end-left.png) left top no-repeat, url(images/footer-end-right.png) right top no-repeat, url(images/footer-center.png) center top repeat-x, #C4C4C4;
}
```

Comment: Which version of IE have you tried?

Comment: I have only tried version 8 and below. I tried to go on my website at school, and that is when I realized what was up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Multiple backgrounds are not supported by IE < 9](http://www.caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds).

Answer (score 4):

Internet Explorer only supports one background-image at a time. Multiple background-images are part of CSS 3.