# Two background images in one element, but IE doesnt show it

Tags: css, image

I have a Sharepoint site and I want to change the logo. I want to have one picture to the left and one to the right side.  So I created and uploaded a doublelogo.css file in the site's assets, containing the following:

```
.s4-title {
    background: url(PIC1.jpg), url(PIC2.jpg);
    background-color:#FFCC00;

    background-position: left, right;

    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    min-height:99px
}
```

after that i adds a reference to the `<HEAD>` section of my site (v4.master file) which is :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/siteassets/doublelogo.css" media="screen" />
```

opening my site with Chrome, it works as expected. Even when I tested the pictures by zooming in and out the browser window, the pics where steady left and right. OK

But the problem is whenever i open the site with my ie8 or ie9.

I read there is a workaround about putting one div into another but i need help on that because i dont really understand the procedure.

Can someone assist me ?

(i actually want to have two logo because when i had one, and changing the resolution of my computer, the logo was increasing or decreasing, something i do no want.)

Comment: Don't mix the shorthand `background` and separate background properties like `background-color` in one style rule. Some browsers may not handle that correctly. Either use only `background`, or write out all the separate properties in full.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423172/can-i-have-multiple-background-images-using-css, which talks about the nested divs solution. You'll either need to do that or use a polyfill for IE7/8 support.

Comment: Mr Lister>> you are absolutely right about shorthand, something very important that almost no post warns you about it. Trial and error led me to the solution of proper syntax.

Comment: ddrace>> well i solved my problem using one div inside the other, so i managed to have 2 backgrounds ... kind of complicated to be done but in the end , the result is what i want.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try `background-image` instead of `background`:

```
background-image: url(PIC1.jpg), url(PIC2.jpg);
```

If you want to support IE8 you can workaround this having two extra divs, IE9 should support two background image URL's.

Look at [**this list**](http://caniuse.com/#search=multiple%20backgrounds) on [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=multiple%20backgrounds) for the browser support of multiple backgrounds.

**Edit:**

I created an example with nested divs:

http://jsfiddle.net/aUMnC

I used `background-color` and the div's have a different size just to show you, and you can simply use `background-image` instead.

Comment: How can i have two extra divs???? this is the proccedure I want someone to explain me , please

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/aUMnC/. I used `background-color` and the div's have a different size just to show you, and you can simply use `background-image` instead

Comment: If this is what you were looking for, I'll update my question with this example:)

Comment: thank you all , using this http://icode4you.net/using-two-background-images-for-one-div-in-ie i made it.

Comment: It's like what I showed you on jsfiddle. Maybe you want to mark my answer as accepted then:) Thanks.

Comment: By clicking on the checkmark left to the answer:) http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png

Answer (score -1):

do it like this: 
example :

```
div.test {
    background-image: url(../pix/logo_quirksmode.gif), url(../pix/logo_quirksmode_inverted.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-position: top left, top right;
    width: 385px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

Comment: Dear User "user1264255">> This way it work ok in Chrome BUT NOT IE.

Comment: Check your formatting and please read the question. The problem was with IE8/9. In IE9 the problem could have been using `background` instead of `background-image` and in IE8 multiple backgrounds are not supported. http://caniuse.com/#search=multiple%20backgrounds