# How to have two background images. One a top banner and the second a textured background?

Tags: css, image, background, banner

I'm starting to work on a website. I would like to have two background images. One would be a banner image at the top similar to the gray strip across the top of stack overflow's website. Then the other image is a image that I would have to create a textured background. This would be like the white space on this website but instead of a color it would be a repeatable image. Websites with the look i'm going for are pinterest.com, subtlepatterns.com, Facebook.com, etc...

I have tried many different things. I tried putting a background in the html tag in the css. That didn't work. I also tried putting two different background images in the body tag. That didn't work because it would just show the first one. I also tried creating the background in it's own class. But when I did that it wouldn't show up at all. Maybe I left something out of the html?

Currently I have Following code:

```
body, div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, code, form, fieldset, legend, input, textarea, p, blockquote, th, td {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-image:url(../images/absurdidad.png);
background-repeat:repeat;
}
```

This has created the main background image that takes up the whole screen like I want it to. Know if I could add the second one just at the top to only repeat horizontally then it'll be great!

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I have multiple background images using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423172/can-i-have-multiple-background-images-using-css)

Answer (score 5):

using commas, you can have multiple background in the same element:

```
background-image: url('first'), url('second');
```

and the same rule apply for other styling:

```
background-position: top, bottom;
```

And so on.

More informations @ [css3.info](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/)

If you want widespread browser support, multiple DIVs is the only way to do it:

```
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
  </div>
</div>
```

Good luck!

Comment: I never knew that you could do the background-position: top, bottom; that's great to know. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know of to do this is to have multiple wrapper tags with background associated with them.  For example:

```
<div style="background-image:url(../images/image1.png);">
    <div style="background-image:url(../images/image2.png);">
        <!-- div content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had put it in the div tag and it didn't work but it's because I was missing the fact that it had to be a wrapper tag with "style" in it. This is great! Thank you so much!

Comment: Well, it doesn't really have to be, my main point by illustration was to put an outer div and an inner div, each with images.  I used the style tag here to hard-code the images, but you can also use css classes or ids, which is actually a better practice if you'll be inserting a lot of images in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a jsFiddle I just made:
[**jsFiddle Banner and Repeatable Background**](http://jsfiddle.net/9UNcq/)

CSS:

```
body{
    background-image:url("http://silviahartmann.com/background-tile-art/images/grunge-background-seamless-repeating.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    color: white;
}

#headerBackground{
   position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
   height: 50px;
   background-color: gray;
}

#headerContent {
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/700/50/city/5);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="headerBackground">
    <div id="headerContent">Other Header Content</div>
</div>
```

**Update:** Revised jsFiddle with Hotlinkable repeatable background image.

Comment: You are a genius!!! Thank You! Thank You! It worked great! The only thing that I changed was the #headerContent background-repeat to repeat-x. This was wonderful! I could not have done it on my own! :)

Comment: Thank you. Please complete the Stackoverflow Process by accepting this Answer since it resolves your Question. Once you get to 15rep points, then you can also perform a Upvote (This answer is useful) if that applies too.

Answer (score 1):

This will help you [Can I have multiple background images using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423172/can-i-have-multiple-background-images-using-css)

You can use CSS3 to serve multiple backgrounds or some tag trickery to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

size and position you can adjust.Here image2 will repeat.

```
background:url(image1.jpg),url(image2.jpg);
background-size:80px 60px;
-moz-background-size:80px 60px; /* Firefox 3.6 */
background-repeat:no-repeat,repeat;
background-position:top left,center center;
```