# CSS - repeat other then background

Tags: css

I have got set in CSS that some image is background, and when it is over with I want to repeat or I want to continue with other image

something like this:

```
ul.smenu .menu_tlacidlo:hover {   
        background:url(images/sluzby_menu_btn_hover_2.png);   
        background-repeat: "url(images/sluzby_menu_btn_line.png)";  
        width:142px;  
        height: 22px;  
}
```

Is there way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/423190/474535

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423172/can-i-have-multiple-background-images-using-css.