# I want a fixed background attachment in a certain place

Tags: css, background, attachment

Iam new here and new in coding.
I want a background attachment to be placed in a very certain position
top,top left,top right etc  won't do the job, I want a most accurate position
eg. the attachments upleft corner to be placed in 100,200

Comment: Are we talking about the web and CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to be done in `CSS` then go for this

```
div
{
    background-image:url('your-img-url');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:100px 200px;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

Comment: background-attachment: fixed;      
background-color: #F9F9FB;  
    background-image: url("../images/snowguide.png") position: 10px 10px, url("../images/snowguidebgr.png");  
background-repeat:no-repeat,repeat;

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423172/can-i-have-multiple-background-images-using-css) what you want to do??