# How to repeat multiple images over one element using CSS

Tags: css

How do I use CSS to repeat a first background image both vertically and horizontally, and repeat a second background image just horizontally?  I wish it not to be dependent upon CSS3.

I tried the following, but no success.

```
body {
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
body:before,
body:after {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
body:after {
    background-image:url('../images/bg.png');
    background-repeat:repeat;
}
body:before {
    background-image:url('../images/top-bg.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: Care to elaborate? Not following what you need, what context it's in or what you've tried.

Comment: with css you can only repeat a background-image, not an image. If you want to repeat the background-image do the easy thing and google for 'css background-repeat'. The definition is straight forward and doesn't leave questions open.

Comment: Do you mean multiple background images? These are only supported by CSS3, so not all browsers. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423172/can-i-have-multiple-background-images-using-css

Comment: Sorry, meant background-image, not an image.  Problem is I wish to repeat two separate images, one just horizontally and one both horizontally and vertically.

Comment: @MMacdonald.  Exactly!  So it is only possible with CSS3?  Any workarounds for other browsers?

Comment: workaround for other browsers is using two nested container each one with a background-image. The background-image you want on top should be the background-image of the inner container.

Comment: Thanks Sven.  I was thinking that might be the solution, but didn't know if there was anything better.  Post it and I will select it as the answer (provided it works!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [CSS3 multiple backgrounds](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/). Supported since Firefox 3.6, Safari 1.3, Chrome  10, Opera 10.50 and Internet Explorer 9.0.

If you must support IE8 or earlier (noting that [Google drop support for IE8 from next month](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/09/17/ie8_ditched_by_google/)), either combine the images into 1, or overlay multiple elements.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    #tile, #logo { 
       padding:0; 
       margin:0; 
       border:0; 
       position:absolute; 
       top:0; 
       left:0; 
       right:0; 
       bottom:0;
    }
    #tile{ 
       background-image:url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e7/Procedural_Texture.jpg'); 
       background-repeat:repeat;
    }
    #logo{ 
       background-image:url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/95/Stack_Overflow_website_logo.png'); 
       background-repeat:repeat-x;
    }
    </style>
 </head>
 <body>
<div id="tile"></div>
<div id="logo"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

This may be [one](http://thasha-in-wonderland.blogspot.co.uk/2009/03/multiple-background-images-css3-and.html) of [various](http://nicolasgallagher.com/multiple-backgrounds-and-borders-with-css2/) solutions available.

Comment: Thanks MMacdonald! Tried the multiple element solution, but no success.  I edited my original post to show what I did.

Comment: Posting a complete self-contained code sample is clearer. I edited my answer to suggest one solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
mydiv
{
background-image:url('myimage.jpg');
background-repeat:repeat;
}
```

...will do across both axes

```
mydiv
{
background-image:url('myimage.jpg');
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
```

...will do horizontally.

I'm assuming this is what you're after, your question isn't overly specific, can you state more clearly what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks Lante.  Almost, but I wish to do both at the same time, and use a different image for each.