# multiple background on a:hover using css2

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I have multiple background images using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423172/can-i-have-multiple-background-images-using-css)

I want to use multiple backgrounds on a:hover state using css2, currently I am using css3,

```
background:url(), url();
```

Comment: CSS2 doesn't support multiple backgrounds. What is your question?

Comment: on a:hover i want to use multiple background, I have a one image which is a background for menu li and one image as a icon, that both images should be changed on mouse hover, so can I change both image using css2 only or i need to use javascript, this is my question