# CSS: horizontal menu with two images on each entry side and rollover

Tags: css, html

I'm a beginner in CSS and I can't google the solution to the design challenge I have. 
I would like to have a CSS horizontal menu like this

(entry1) (entry2) (entry3)

, where "(" and ")" are images. I'd also like to change those () images on mouse over.

I'd be extremely grateful for any tip.

Best regards,
Kuba

Comment: So, what exactly is your problem? You've given the context, now say what you're stuck with

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS :

```
.menu li a{
background:transparent url("images/seperator.gif") right no-repeat;
}
```

change `.menu` and `"images/seperator.gif"` with yours

Comment: thx a lot! we're very close. The point is that left and right separator differ.

Comment: So, you can look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423172/can-i-have-multiple-background-images-using-css)