# Combine 2 linear gradients using `background` css?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to create a background gradient for a div that follows this design:
[image: gradient]
The background has a horizontal gradient
`linear-gradient( to right, #84d2ff, #8d5acd)`,
but also has a vertical gradient from white downward (not transparent).

Is is possible to combine these two gradients using CSS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add multiple css gradient as a multiple background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253452/how-to-add-multiple-css-gradient-as-a-multiple-background) and [How to apply multiple css radial gradients to a single element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677429/how-to-apply-multiple-css-radial-gradients-to-a-single-element)

Comment: also this one  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60209914/is-this-possible-to-create-2-axis-4-color-gradient-in-css-bilinear-gradient/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the gradients you apply are non-transparent, so one of them will always lay on top of the other. You'll need to apply a fade effect using alpha values.

The look here for more detail: [How to combine two css3 gradients ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19725150/how-to-combine-two-css3-gradients)

```css
.double-gradient {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(251, 251, 251, 0.1) 100%), linear-gradient(90deg, #84d2ff, #8d5acd);
}
```

```html
<div class="double-gradient">
  Double Gradient
</div>
```