# Centering Another Image On Background Image

Tags: css, image

I have a full background image and I want to add another one on it, something like a logo. I have added that logo however I couldn't center it. Any suggestions for CSS?

This is the CSS for now:

```
.center-logo {
  position: absolute;  
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Related, though not duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423172/can-i-have-multiple-background-images-using-css

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the `background-position` for each image to position it to your requirement.

[**MDN Reference**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position)

> The background-position CSS property sets the initial position,
>   relative to the background position layer defined by background-origin
>   for each defined background image.

**Position value**

> It is one to four values representing a 2D position regarding the edges of the element's box. Relative or
>   absolute offsets can be given. Note that the position can be set
>   outside of the element's box.

---

```css
body {
  background:  url(http://placehold.it/200x200/333), url(http://placehold.it/1200x1200);
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
  background-position: center top, center top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved it with the following codes:

HTML:

```
<div class="center-main">
        <div class="center-in"><img class="centered-logo" src="images/logo.png" style="margin-top:-70px;" /></div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.center-main {
    width:500px;
    height: 250px;
    display: table;
    position: relative; 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 auto;  
}

.center-main .center-in {
    position: fixed; 
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle;  
}

.center-main .center-in .centered-logo {
    max-width:300px;
    max-height:150px;
    position: relative; 
    top: -50%;
    left:-50%;  
}
```