# How to add another imgae to a div without replacing the first one using Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

Suppose we have already the first image.

```
.bg{
    background-image: url('img/bg1.png');
}
```

Then we wanna add another image img/bg2.png using Angular 2. How could we do that?

I tried to use

```
<div [style.background-image]="getBg()"></div>
```

while

```
getBg(){
    return "url('img/bg2.png')";
}
```

However, it will replace the bg1.png.
So how could I add another background image to the div above?
Thanks.

edit:
I know we should use comma, but how could we get the first image using Angular 2?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a comma-separated list of URLs:

```
getBg(){
    return "url('img/bg1.png'),url('img/bg2.png')";
}
```

See also [Can I have multiple background images using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423172/can-i-have-multiple-background-images-using-css)