# How to add multiple images in background body

Tags: html, css

So I wanted to make a site where I could have the background have a header image of say `600px` image, that being the "`site background`," then having the rest be a tiled image, as well as that I wanted the header background to adapt to movement, like `background-position: center;` CSS property.

I looked at `W3` but their documentation is confusing. [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_backgrounds.asp)

This is some code I tried:

```
background: url(bg.png) top, url(tile.png) repeat;
```

But I'm not sure how I'd be able to add `background-position & height` into that.

Comment: good old google: css background multiple images<br>
result: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423172/can-i-have-multiple-background-images-using-css

Comment: THAT ISN'T THE W3 PAGE ... sorry for mayus but this is big xd

Comment: https://www.w3.org/

Answer (score 1):

Short example:

```css
.web {
    width: 800px;
    height: 1000px;
    background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/800x600/000/fff), url(https://dummyimage.com/800x300/555/fff);
    background-size: 300px 200px, 300px 100px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-position: center 0px, center 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="web"></div>
```