# how can i repeat the background image of chain link fence

Tags: css, web, background, png

Trying to repeat this chain link fence down along the sides with a repeat-y, and I have another image also repeating just fine here... what am I doing wrong that this wont repeat?

WEBSITE
http://www51.myfantasyleague.com/2017/home/32545#0

```
body {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    background-image: url("http://www.dagrafixdesigns.com/Images/2008/DA_2017/zCasey_25540/bars1.png"), 
                      url("http://dagrafixdesigns.com/Images/2008/DA_2017/zWB_17/bg_1.jpg");
    background-position: 50% 0%, center top;
    background-repeat: repeat-y, repeat;
    color: #ccc;
    font: 400 11pt "Oswald",sans-serif;
    height: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which browser are you testing in? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423172/can-i-have-multiple-background-images-using-css

Comment: firefox...but shows same in chrome...that top fence image isn't repeating down

Comment: your fence has a 1920x1080 resolution. i think that this is to big to repeat, right? cut the unnecessary height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your pattern file isn't correct. The pattern file has a really big white space around the pattern, and that white space is also "repeated".

[Link to the pattern image from your own website](http://www.dagrafixdesigns.com/Images/2008/DA_2017/zCasey_25540/bars1.png)

Therefore, you must remove such white space in a graphics editor, like Photoshop.