# css 3 images in td

Tags: html, css, image, html-table

I'm having trouble adding 3 images to a table cell in css and was wondering if anyone could help me to figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Here is what I have:

css

```
.Example {
        background-image:url("image1.gif"),url("image2.gif"),url("image3.gif");
    background-position: top left, top center, top right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-x, no-repeat;
}
```

html

```
<td class="Example">
    <a href="example">Example</a>
</td>
```

When I open the page however, all I get is a cell that says Example with no background image.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What browser are you trying this in? This is relatively new and not yet fully supported in all browsers. Do the images exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
.Example {
background-image:url("image1.gif"),url("image2.gif"),url("image3.gif");
background-position: top left, top center, top right;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

without the three parameters on background-repeat.

And keep in mind that this is not working on every browser.

I suggest you use the old fashion way to resolve this. Put a link on every picture with the same href.

Answer (score 1):

> The only browser projects having this
>   feature implemented so far are WebKit
>   and KHTML (Konqueror). This got into
>   Safari 1.3 though, and works in
>   OmniWeb 5.5 and up.

[Source](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/)

Answer (score 1):

Having multiple background images in the same element and the current limitations have been answered here: [**layering-images-in-css-possible-to-put-2-images-in-same-element**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402200/layering-images-in-css-possible-to-put-2-images-in-same-element) and also here: [**an-i-have-multiple-background-images-using-css**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423172/can-i-have-multiple-background-images-using-css)

Currently not all browsers support that feature as stated in the answers in the above links.
There is also suggestions to work-arounds, such as using multiple Divs and placing each image into its own div and using z-orders to display divs as required.