# can i use two images as background in a html div

Tags: css, html

Is it possible to use two images for div background in css. That is i have two images. one just the background color and the other logo. I am using the code some what like this.

```
        .header{
        background-attachment: scroll;
        background-clip: border-box;
        background-color: transparent;
        background-image: url("./img/logo.png");
        background-origin: padding-box;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 400px 90px;
        height: 90px;
        width:100%
        -webkit-border-radius:7px;
        background: url(img/header_background.jpg) repeat-x;

            }
```

whats happening is the last image i declared in background its overwriting previous. Could anyone let  me know the solution for this

Comment: If the "background color" image is just a solid color, you can just set it directly with `background-color: XXX`

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423172/can-i-have-multiple-background-images-using-css

Comment: `background` is shorthand for the properties above it. That's not specifically your problem, but something to also watch out for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Layering images in CSS - possible to put 2 images in same element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402200/layering-images-in-css-possible-to-put-2-images-in-same-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 2 div's for that,

you can stay with .header but there should be div with class header_logo inside

i.e.

```
.header{
        background-attachment: scroll;
        background-clip: border-box;
        background-color: transparent;
        background-image: url("./img/logo.png");
        background-origin: padding-box;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 400px 90px;
        height: 90px;
        width:100%
        -webkit-border-radius:7px;
 }

.header_logo {

        height: 90px;
        width:100px;    
        background: url(img/header_background.jpg) repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: actually you don't need to have 2 divs. Isn't it? http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/

Answer (score 1):

Use a comma-separated list of background properties to define multiple backgrounds. This feature is only available in the most recent browsers though.

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-image

**Extra info:**
Adding `background` after a bunch of `background-` properties overwrite all of the previously defined background-properties. The reverse order, however doesn't:

```
background: red;
background-image: url("transparent-circle.png");
/*Shows the image, with a red color at the transparent sections of the image*/
```

Answer (score 0):

In `CSS3` you can use [Multiple Backgrounds](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/). But you probobly will have issues with `IE`